# Trouble create new instance of model in Rails, path missing?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the error I'm getting:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Books#show
Showing /Users/bardiap/saasapp/app/views/chapters/_index.html.erb where line #3 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"chapters", :id=>"2"}, missing required keys: [:book_id]
```

Here are the relevant files:

_index.html.erb

```
<h1>Chapters</h1>

<%= link_to 'New chapter', book_chapter_path %>


  <% @chapters.each do |chapter| %>
    <ul class="demo-list-item mdl-list">
      <li class="mdl-list__item">
        <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
          <%=link_to '@chapter',book_chapter_path(chapter)%>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_chapter_path(chapter) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', book_chapter_path(chapter),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

  <%end%>
```

relevant routes

```
                   chapters#index     POST   /books/:book_id/chapters(.:format)                                                        chapters#create
                     new_book_chapter GET    /books/:book_id/chapters/new(.:format)                                                    chapters#new
                    edit_book_chapter GET    /books/:book_id/chapters/:id/edit(.:format)                                               chapters#edit
                         book_chapter GET    /books/:book_id/chapters/:id(.:format)                                                    chapters#show
                                      PATCH  /books/:book_id/chapters/:id(.:format)                                                    chapters#update
                                      PUT    /books/:book_id/chapters/:id(.:format)                                                    chapters#update
                                      DELETE /books/:book_id/chapters/:id(.:format)                                                    chapters#destroy
                                books GET    /books(.:format)                                                                          books#index
                                      POST   /books(.:format)                                                                          books#create
                             new_book GET    /books/new(.:format)                                                                      books#new
                            edit_book GET    /books/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                 books#edit
                                 book GET    /books/:id(.:format)                                                                      books#show
                                      PATCH  /books/:id(.:format)                                                                      books#update
                                      PUT    /books/:id(.:format)                                                                      books#update
                                      DELETE /books/:id(.:format)
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "bookcover_file_name"
    t.string "bookcover_content_type"
    t.integer "bookcover_file_size"
    t.datetime "bookcover_updated_at"
    t.string "authorpic_file_name"
    t.string "authorpic_content_type"
    t.integer "authorpic_file_size"
    t.datetime "authorpic_updated_at"
    t.string "author"
    t.string "month"
  end

  create_table "chapters", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "book_id"
    t.index ["book_id"], name: "index_chapters_on_book_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

All of those nested routes require a `@book` object (check your `rake routes` output where it says `:book_id`), which you are not providing.

See the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) (just before section 2.7.1) where it says:

> This will also create routing helpers such as magazine_ads_url and edit_magazine_ad_path. These helpers take an instance of Magazine as the first parameter (magazine_ads_url(@magazine)).

For instance, this:

```
<%= link_to 'New chapter', book_chapter_path %>
```

should look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'New chapter', new_book_chapter_path(@book) %>
```

NOTE: You should be using `new_book_chapter_path` here, not `book_chapter_path`.

This:

```
<%=link_to '@chapter',book_chapter_path(chapter)%>
```

Should look like this:

```
<%=link_to '@chapter', book_chapter_path(@book, chapter)%>
```

NOTE: That `'@chapter'` doesn't make any sense unless you want the link to show as the literal string `'@chapter'`. Instead, it should probably be something like:

```
<%=link_to chapter.title, book_chapter_path(@book, chapter)%>
```

Or, alternatively,

```
<%=link_to chapter.title, [@book, chapter] %>
```

You should instantiate the `@book` variable in your controller (as you showed in your previous question).

Comment: how do I provide a @book object and where?

Comment: Ok so that worked, but now I have this error on my new chapter page:
NoMethodError in Chapters#new
Showing /Users/bardiap/saasapp/app/views/chapters/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `chapters_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fa6406af200>:0x00007fa6406ac5f0>

    <%= form_with model: @chapter, local: true do |form| %>

Comment: Naturally. In the paths you posted, there is not named path `chapters`.